# What's the difference between filename and ./filename in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, path, filenames

What is the difference between `filename` and `./filename`?  Under what circumstances is one preferred to the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For datafiles, it does not make a difference - both statements will reference the data file in your current directory. (For example, `cat filename` and `cat ./filename` are semantically identical.)

It's a different story if the filename in question refers to an *executable*, i.e. is the first (or even only) thing you type on the command line. `./filename` will look for the executable in your current directory, and nowhere else. `filename`, on the other hand, will evaluate the environment variable `PATH`, and look for `filename` in every directory stored therein (which might or might not include your current directory).

`./filename` (or any other `/path/to/filename`) is thus preferred when you want to execute a *specific* executable, not the first one found in your PATH.

Answer (score 6):

If you're running a program, `filename` says to run the first one found in your `$PATH` and the second one says to run the one in the current directory.

If you're using that filename as an argument to a program as in `do_something filename` or `do_something ./filename` then they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

You are referring to command execution, right?

There is an enviroment variable `PATH` that contains some system directories, delimited by semicolon. When you type `command` the system looks in these directories in the order they are specified to find an executable file named <command> If it finds it, it tries to execute it. You can see your PATH via `echo $PATH` in bash. For example:

> $ echo $PATH
>   /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/ivanatora/bin:/usr/local/kde4/bin:/usr/local/kde4/bin

When you type `./filename` you are specifying exact path: the current directory. You can see that the current directory seldom is in your $PATH (for security reasons). So if you want to execute a file from the current directory, you use `./filename`.

To execute a file by its path (especialy if it is not in $PATH) you can also type `<path>/file`, like:

> /sbin/ifconfig

Answer (score 3):

Executable security is the main reason for this difference.

You do not want . (present working directory or PWD) in your path because someone could trojan
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_%28computing%29
a crucial executable like ps or ls, in your PWD and fool you by presenting bad data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what circumstances you're using it as.

As an argument, eg "program filename", then it's up to the program, but generally they're identical.

As a program name, eg "filename arguments", then "filename arguments" will search PATH to find the binary, while "./filename arguments" will use the program in the current directory. This is obviously useful if . isn't in the PATH, but it's also useful to use this one even if . is in the path, perhaps because it matches an earlier entry.